# Looking for a jquery regex pattern to match 0-24, allowing decimals

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm setting up a form field that allows users to enter hours for a task. I want the field to allow between 0 and 24 hours, with 2-place decimals.

The initial regex I wrote handles it, but forces the decimal and decimal digits.

```
^([0-9](\.\d{1,2}))|([1]\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2}))|([2][0-3](\.\d{1,2}))|24$
```

I tried setting the decimal capture groups as optional:

```
^([0-9](\.\d{1,2})?)|([1]\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)|([2][0-3](\.\d{1,2})?)|24$
```

but then it allows goofy numbers like "23.999999999".

And yes, in this instance, the regex is the method preferred. Not functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^((?:[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:\.\d{1,2})?|24(?:\.00?)?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cR9oB9/1)

Comment: Why does the last capturing group have anything other than "24" in it? Just Curious.

Comment: To be able to match `24.00`. If that's not a valid input then just remove `(?:\.00?)?` from end.

Comment: Your pattern does exactly as asked, and it's shorter than my original. Elegant. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really neat site called regex101 (https://regex101.com/#javascript) that I use sometimes when making regexes.

I put together this one that might work for you

```
^\d(\.\d?\d?)?$|^(?=1)1\d(\.\d?\d?)?$|^(?=2)2[0-3](\.\d?\d?)?$|^24$
```

There are 4 alternate cases, with each case being required to match exactly with ^ and $

1. any digit (0-9) with an optional decimal of either 1 or 2 places
2. first digit is 1, any digit in second position (0-9) with an optional decimal
3. first digit is 2, second digit must be one of 0-3 with an optional decimal
4. exactly 24

Comment: Actually, I was using regex101 to test my pattern as I was writing it. :) That said, "24.99" goes through that regex as a "pass" instead of a "fail".

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll adjust it to see if I can account for that

Comment: `^([0-9](\.\d{1,2})?)$|^([1]\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)$|^([2][0-3](\.\d{1,2})?)$|^24$` does the trick. I utterly forgot to start and finish each group as its own string. Your answer completely reminded me of that! :)