# Input type=text pattern numerical with min and max

Tags: html, input, pattern-matching

```
<input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" required pattern=""/>
```

I strictly wanted to use input of **type text** that has a numerical pattern with **min=0** and **max=24**

This question is somewhat duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786775/pattern-for-input-type-text-with-min-and-max-number)

But their maximum is **5000** while mine is **24**

I don't know how to modify the code that's why I ask it again.

The code to limit the input to 5000

```
 <input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" required="required"
 pattern="(5000|([1-4][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|[1-9])"/>
```

How can I make it to **24**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a jquery regex pattern to match 0-24, allowing decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015187/looking-for-a-jquery-regex-pattern-to-match-0-24-allowing-decimals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain how it works so that you can do it yourself next time. There may be a better approach. I just followed the example you mentioned in the description -

```
<input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" required="required" pattern="(([1-2][0-4])|([1][5-9])|[0-9])"/>
```

`pattern` attribute will evaluate the regex
the patter is divided into three parts -

```
(a) [0-9] - this will allow numbers from 0-9

(b) ([1][5-9]) - this will allow numbers from 15 to 19

(c) ([1-2][0-4]) - this will allow numbers from 10 to 14 and 20 to 24
```